# Where is chrome emulation tool in v49+

Tags: google-chrome

I updated chrome to v49+ and I can't find the emulation tool anymore. 
The interface of the device mode changed a lot. And it seems that they change the position of the emulation tab.
Any help with it?

**EDIT**: In general, I want to emulate print view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for dev tools:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/device-mode/

Comment: I still can't find where the option to check on print view.